# How is the identity mapping from $\Bbb{R_\ell}\to\Bbb{R}$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Munkres' book on Topology (Pg 122 of the Second edition) says

> The identity mapping $f:\Bbb{R_\ell}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ (identity mapping) is continuous

I don't understand how. An open set in $\Bbb{R}$ would be of the form $(a,b)$. $f^{-1}(a,b)=(a,b)$, as it is an identity mapping. But $(a,b)$ is not an open set in $\Bbb{R_\ell}$. How is $f$ a continuous mapping then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(a,b)=\bigcup\limits_{a<c<b}[c,b)$ is a union of open sets hence open in $\Bbb R_\ell$.

Comment: Why is $(a,b)$ not open in $\mathbb{R}_{l}$. $\mathbb{R}_{l}$ is strictly finer than $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Tian- I just got why that is. It's a pretty neat argument!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a + \frac{1}{n} , b )$?